# changing listBox items dynamically when selection changes in comboBox

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a comboBox which allows user to choose the selection they want. Based on the selection of the comboBox, i would display the listBox with a list of strings that is related to the user selection.

Example: User chooses "Animals" on comboBox, listBox will display "Monkeys, Horses, Pigs".

Trying to create this simple binding with minimal coding( XAML driven) but to no avail for 1 day. Thanks in advance!

Edit:

Hi for those interested in doing it another way (using only the xaml and a class to store all your data) you could check out the answer by Jehof in the link provided. It is quite a simple way to achieve this.

[ListBox does not display the binding data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15494963/listbox-does-not-display-the-binding-data)

Comment: post your current XAML and code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a quick example of what you are looking for(to get you started).

First create an object that contains all your data and bind that to the `ComboBox`, the use the Comboboxes `SelectedItem` to populate the `ListBox`.

Code:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    { 
        InitializeComponent(); 
        Categories.Add(new Category { Name = "Animals", Items = new List<string> { "Dog", "Cat", "Horse" } });
        Categories.Add(new Category { Name = "Vehicles", Items = new List<string> { "Car", "Truck", "Boat" } });

    }

    private ObservableCollection<Category> _categories = new ObservableCollection<Category>();
    public ObservableCollection<Category> Categories
    {
        get { return _categories; }
        set { _categories = value; }
    }
}

public class Category
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<string> Items { get; set; }
}
```

Xaml:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication10.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525" Name="UI">

        <StackPanel DataContext="{Binding ElementName=UI}">
            <ComboBox x:Name="combo" ItemsSource="{Binding Categories}" DisplayMemberPath="Name"/>
            <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding SelectedItem.Items, ElementName=combo}"/>
        </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

Result:

[image] [image] [image]

Comment: thank you for your prompt reply, because i tend not to use the code behind to put in my data, i have a class used to store all the data. So the problem i have is in binding my listBox items to the list of string found in the data class.

Comment: well since you never mentioned that or posted any relevant code this it the best guess I could make to what you wanted, perhaps you should add ALL your requirements to the question so someone else can help.

Comment: well thank you anw, this is the solution to the question posted. Will post up the solution once i found it