# ListBox does not display the binding data

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

In my Xaml i have this,

```
<ComboBox x:Name="masterCB" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="5,127,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="106" Height="22" Background="White" ItemsSource="{Binding Masters}" FontSize="11" SelectedIndex="{Binding Action}"/>
        <Label Content="Select Action:" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="26" Width="116" Margin="0,151,0,0" Background="{x:Null}" FontWeight="Bold"/>

<ListBox x:Name="actionBox" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="250" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="116" Margin="5,177,0,0" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" 
            ItemsSource="{Binding ActionList}" AlternationCount="2" MouseDoubleClick="actionBox_DoubleClick">
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Grid Background="{x:Null}">
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" TextTrimming="WordEllipsis" TextWrapping="Wrap" Height="40" FontSize="11" />
                    </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="ItemsControl.AlternationIndex" Value="1">
                            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Silver"/>
                        </Trigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
```

In my data class i have this,

```
private List<String> actionList;
public int Action 
   { 
       get{return this.action;} 
       set
       {
           action = value;
           populateActionList();
       } 
   }
 public List<String> ActionList
   {
       get { return actionList; }
       set { this.actionList = value; }
   private void populateActionList()
   {
       if (this.action == 0)
       {
           actionList = new List<String> { 
       "Chinese",
       "Indian",
       "Malay",
       "Indian",
       };
       if (this.action == 1)
       {
           actionList = new List<String> { 
       "Dog",
       "Cats",
       "Pigs",
       "Horses",
       "Fish",
       "Lion"};
       }
   }
```

When i do a printline, my actionList is changed, but the ListBox item is not set to my actionList. Would just like to know why and how come the UI does not update? I read somewhere that you would have to change to DataContext and ObservableCollections  but i tried that one out and it still does not update. Does anyone know why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Changing your code to the following, will do what you expect

```
private ObservableCollection<String> _actionList; 

public ObservableCollection<String> ActionList {
  get { 
    if (_actionList == null) {
      _actionList = new ObservableCollection<String>();
    }

    return actionList; 
  }
}

private void populateActionList(){
  if (this.action == 0) {
    ActionList.Clear();

    ActionList.Add("Chinese");
    ActionList.Add("Indian");
    ActionList.Add("Malay");
    ActionList.Add("Indian");
  }

  if (this.action == 1){
    ActionList.Clear();

    ActionList.Add("Dog");
    ActionList.Add("Cats");
    ActionList.Add("Pigs");
    ActionList.Add("Horses");
    ActionList.Add("Fish");
    ActionList.Add("Lion");
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi thx for the answer, i finally understand what went wrong with my codes. will upvote once i have enough reps. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

I copied all of your code, and ran it in a new WPF app.

In order to fix your binding issue, there are two ways:

1st: make a Loaded event on your main window, with the following code:

```
private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    DataContext = this;
    populateActionList();
}
```

this gives the following in my app:

[image: pic of app]

2nd: You can also bind this in XAML like so:

in your MainWindow.xaml:

Add the following to the window tag:

**DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"**

Then in your constructor, make sure you set your data before InitializeComponent() is run:

```
public MainWindow()
{
   populateActionList();
   InitializeComponent();
}
```

Comment: Hi thx for the answer, but the problem is that i am not using the main window but instead a data class to store all my data(ie. Indian Chinese Malay are all stored in this class). Therefore, i am unable to use any method to invoke the populateActionList() automatically.

Comment: In that case, Jehof's code should work. Make sure to set the data context still, either in code or xaml, otherwise when you databind the observable collection to the xaml it may not update. The reason for using ObservableCollection is it raises Collection/PropertyChanged events when the collection/data changes.

Answer (score 2):

In your case, you can also work with Lists if you want, because you are replacing the whole list and not adding/removing single items. For that, you would have to use ObservableCollection, like Jehof wrote, which is automatically firing CollectionChanged events (*not* PropertyChanged) when add/remove/clear/replace actions are executed on the collection.

You need to change two things to get your code to work:

1. Correctly implement INotifyPropertyChanged in your viewmodel. For each property that you databind, you will need to fire the PropertyChanged event in the setter. See my code below.
2. Do not change your private `actionList` field, instead change your property `ActionList`, when you want bindings to be updated, because when you change your field, the PropertyChanged event is not fired.

The thing to keep in mind is: Your UI listens to PropertyChanged and CollectionChanged events of the properties it is databound to. So if your UI does not get updated, these events are usually not fired.

ViewModel:

```
public class ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if (this.PropertyChanged != null)
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

    // Masters
    private List<string> _masters = new List<string>() { "Actions 0", "Actions 1" };
    public List<string> Masters { get { return _masters; } set { _masters = value; OnPropertyChanged("Masters"); } }

    // Action
    private int action;
    public int Action { get { return this.action; } set { action = value; PopulateActionList(); OnPropertyChanged("Action"); } }

    // ActionList
    private List<String> actionList;
    public List<String> ActionList { get { return actionList; } set { this.actionList = value; OnPropertyChanged("ActionList"); } }


    private void PopulateActionList()
    {
        if (this.action == 0)
            this.ActionList = new List<String> { "Chinese", "Indian", "Malay", "Indian" };
        else if (this.action == 1)
            this.ActionList = new List<String> { "Dog", "Cats", "Pigs", "Horses", "Fish", "Lion" };
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you! i learned a new thing today. Would upvote once i get enough rep but till then u have my gratitude:)

Answer (score 1):

`ActionList` should be `ObservableCollection<string>`.

You should set `DataContext` of your window to the object with property `ActionList`

Comment: Changing it to ObservableCollection would not solve his problem. He replaces the value of the property ActionList, and therefore needs to raise the PropertyChanged event for property ActionList.

Comment: You ara right :-) Another way is to replace content of existing collection instead of creating new instance.

Comment: Hi guys, thx for your replies but if i am not wrong if i use ObservableCollection, doesnt it already raise the PropertyChanged events for changes in its own property(ie. actionList)?

Comment: `PropertyChanged` will be raised when you add element to `ObservableCollection`, but not when you replace property value with another instance of `ObservableCollection`. You can raise it manually or clear and fill existing collection instead of creating new one.

Comment: `CollectionChanged`will be raised on collection changes, not `PropertyChanged`.